# PHP get next element in array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have 2 shipping zones, A & B. Orders for zone A are delivered each Monday, Wednesday & Friday, whereas zone B is on Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday. For each order, the delivery day is scheduled for the NEXT AVAILABLE day, depending on the zone. Please consider that if someone places an order on Monday the goods will be delivered on the NEXT available date, that would be Tuesday for zone B and Wednesday for zone A.

So far it works ok but there's one last thing I need to do, this is the code http://ideone.com/vpL0N

Please go down to the last lines and read my comment, it explains what i need. I believe it would work if I advanced to the next element in the $zones array, cant' figure it out though.

Thanks!

Comment: No, its for an OSCommerce-based website that sells fresh goods (www.emanaviko.gr) and I've been asked to do a few tweaks so that customers know when the goods will be delivered.

Comment: bikey77, you should add the code you've got a problem with to the question (not linking). Keep the code to the needed minimum to describe your problem (e.g. the array data and then the part you have problems in access). Your description is nice, but the technical problem should be worded cleanly. In the end it won't play a role if that are order zones or colors of some ice-cream flavors.

Comment: I thought it would be easier for all of you if there was less code and a way you could test the code online.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php next method to get next value in array.

```
<?php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'car';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

Comment: I already read about next() on PHP.net and found the exact same example, thing is that when I use it I get an error, probably because of misuse: $next = next($zones[$zone][$week]);

Comment: yes, there could be issue with you array. please try print_r($zones[$zone][$week]); and tell me what it displays.